# Where is a 302 temporary redirect code located?

Tags: apache, http, redirect, web

Where would a [302 temporary redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) code located within a website's files? I am struggling to find it and would like to change it to a 301 permanent. I tried `.htaccess` which I thought would be the most obvious location for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to redirect the whole site or just one subdirectory?
If the whole site, you'll need to edit the .htaccess file in the root of the site.  If a directory, you'll need to create an .htaccess file in that directory that will then control everything below that directory.

[This is a simple 302 redirect](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htaccess/ht/ht302redirect.htm)

Comment: Thanks !Not entirely sure, I might need to redirect the whole website as I changed domain name and server. What do you recommend in this case?

Comment: Yea that sounds like you need to put it in the root of the website. If you're having trouble with .htaccess and have another domain, you could just empty all files from the server except an index file with some javascript redirecting to the new site.  Not best-practice but you wouldn't have to deal with .htaccess

Comment: Thanks, I will empty the whole lot. It shouldn't be a problem and will reveal which file i need to redirect on my new website. I am still confused though, is the 302 redirect an actual piece of code within htaccess ?

Comment: yea its basically one line of code that tells the server to point all incoming traffic to wherever you specify in the code

Comment: How come I can't see it though? I made the redirect through my internet service provider. Where do they put it?

Comment: ah ok.  the file is in the root directory of your website but it's hidden.  all files with a period in front of them are system files that are hidden from users unless they either specify them to be visible or use certain tools (select 'show system files' in an ftp client).  every computer has tons of system files that are hidden so the user doesn't accidentally mess with anything important and so all the filesystems are less cluttered